# Mysql : Pivot table According to status

Tags: mysql

My DB structure and details below

```
CREATE TABLE `tbldakmst` (
`inwardId` int(11) NOT NULL,
`dakType` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`dakMarkTo` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`letterNo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`markDeptt` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`dakSenderName` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
`subject` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
`remarks` text,
`comments` text,
`handoverDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`handoverTo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`forwardedTo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`forwardedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`forwardedFrom` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` enum('0','1','2','3','4','5') DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0=>CREATED, 1=>MARK TO, 2 => FORWARD TO, 3=>INITIATED, 4=>INITIATED AND DISPOSED, 5=>DISPOSED',
`createdBy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`createdOn` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`modifiedBy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `modifiedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`fileInitiateBy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`fileInitiatedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`disposedBy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`disposedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `tbldakmst` (`inwardId`, `dakType`, `dakMarkTo`, `letterNo`, `markDeptt`, `dakSenderName`, `subject`, `remarks`, `comments`, `handoverDate`, `handoverTo`, `forwardedTo`, `forwardedOn`, `forwardedFrom`, `status`, `createdBy`, `createdOn`, `modifiedBy`, `modifiedOn`, `fileInitiateBy`, `fileInitiatedOn`, `disposedBy`, `disposedOn`) VALUES
            (1, 0, 3, 'letter 5634', 'Office Dak', 'dheeraj kumar nayak', 'My subject data is here', 'Remrks Datammm VBCBCBBBBB', 'disposed again', '1970-01-26 00:00:00', 3, 3, '2017-05-02 15:14:50', 2, '5', 2, '2017-05-01 17:40:32', 3, '2017-05-07 15:42:40', 3, '2017-05-07 14:07:35', 3, '2017-05-07 14:39:51'),
            (2, 0, 4, 'letter no 787887', 'Office Dak', 'kAMLESH kUMAR', 'subj', 'Remarks  data', 'MY COMMENTS', '2017-05-02 15:14:50', 4, 2, '2017-05-02 15:14:50', 2, '2', 0, '2017-05-02 11:13:00', 2, '2017-05-05 13:00:44', NULL, NULL, 2, NULL),
            (3, 0, 2, 'letter 5634', 'Office Dak', 'dheeraj kumar nayak', 'Need operator credentiasl', 'file putted edited', 'gdfgfg', '1970-01-01 00:00:00', 2, 3, NULL, 2, '1', 2, '2017-05-03 11:03:49', 2, '2017-05-04 14:48:48', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
            (4, 0, 2, 'letter 567', 'Office Dak', 'Dheraj Kumar', 'operator activation request from CSC-SPV', 'Personal Visit by EA', 'Disposed Now', '2017-05-07 00:00:00', 2, 2, NULL, 3, '5', 3, '2017-05-07 15:46:06', 2, '2017-05-07 16:10:14', 2, '2017-05-07 16:09:17', 2, '2017-05-07 16:10:14'),
            (5, 0, 3, 'letter no 5566rr', 'Office Dak', 'ranjeet vaghle', 'operator request', 'proceed', 'File issues resolved and file is diposed', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 3, 2, NULL, 3, '4', 3, '2017-05-07 15:55:32', 2, '2017-05-07 16:06:58', 2, '2017-05-07 16:06:58', 2, '2017-05-07 16:06:58'),
            (6, 0, 2, 'letter 5634', 'Office Dak', 'dheeraj kumar nayak', 'hjjh', 'hjkhj', NULL, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, '1', 2, '2017-05-07 17:27:36', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
            (7, 0, 2, 'Letter Number -56788899', 'Office Dak', 'dheeraj kumar nayak', 'dsfs', 'fdsfdsf', 'initiated', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 2, 2, NULL, 2, '3', 2, '2017-05-07 17:51:56', 2, '2017-05-07 17:52:54', 2, '2017-05-07 17:52:54', NULL, NULL);


ALTER TABLE `tbldakmst`
              ADD PRIMARY KEY (`inwardId`);
ALTER TABLE `tbldakmst` MODIFY `inwardId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
```

I have tried:

```
        SELECT 
            sum(CASE
                WHEN status = '1'   THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) AS 'pending',
             sum(CASE
                WHEN status = '3' THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) AS 'initiated',
             sum(CASE
                WHEN status = '4' OR status = '5' THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) AS 'disposed' FROM  tbldakmst

        Above Query Output Was :

        pending     initiated   disposed        
        2              1           3         


 <!-- Note:Status(0,1) ==>Pending ,Status (3) ==>Initiated,Status(4,5)==>Disposed
 column FileInitiatedBy => User Value which one has initiated file.
 Column disposedBy=> User Value which one has disposed file.
 Column dakmarkTo => User Value which one have pending file -->
```

But I want Result  Like this

```
        User           |  Pending    | Initiated | Disposed  |
        ------------------------------------------------------
        User 2         |    1        |   1       |    2      |
        ------------------------------------------------------
        User 3         |     2       |   3       |    4      |
        ------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: SELECT sum(CASE WHEN status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'pending', sum(CASE WHEN status = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'initiated', sum(CASE WHEN status = '4' OR status = '5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'disposed' FROM tbldakmst

Comment: It feels like there's a lot of stuff here that's not really relevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

SELECT u.name AS 'Name', 
    sum(CASE
        WHEN tb.status in ('0','1') AND (u.id = tb.dakMarkTo OR u.id = tb.createdBy) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'pending' ,
     sum(CASE
        WHEN tb.status in ('3') AND u.id = tb.fileInitiateBy THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'initiated',
     sum(CASE
        WHEN tb.status in ('4', '5') AND u.id = tb.disposedBy THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'disposed'

FROM
    tbldakmst tb, user u
    group by u.name